# Native module - best convention when returning promise

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm creating a native module for React Native which depends on a 3rd party app.

One of the functions in the module, `isInstalled` checks whether the user has the app installed on the device. The function returns a promise with the result. Obviously if the app is installed the promise will resolve. Currently I'm just returning `resolve(true)`.

I'm in doubt on how to handle the case when the user doesn't have the app installed.

Should I still resolve the promise with `resolve(false)` or is it better to reject the promise, or should that be reserved for actual exceptions?

Comment: This may be too opinion-based for SO, though it's a tough call.

Comment: I tend to prefer only rejecting promises if something went wrong with answering the question, not if the answer to the question is "no".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to think of it is this: should code calling this method have to handle the case where the user doesn't have the app installed? I would say "yes", because this is a very likely scenario.

By resolving with the answer to whether the app is installed or not, you are forcing the consumers of the promise to branch based on the answer.

If instead you reject when the app is not installed, you run the risk of code never attaching an error handler and never dealing with the very likely scenario of the app not being installed.

If the rejection is not handled, it may then show up in error reporting tools like [TrackJS](http://trackjs.com) and in the console as an unhandled promise rejection, which you may or may not see in time to address it.

Answer (score 3):

The general contract is: Resolve if the operation in question worked, reject if it didn't.

So the question is: What is the operation? Given the name `isInstalled`, I'd say the operation is determining whether the app is installed. So it worked if it's able to make that determination (either way, the app is or isn't installed), and didn't work if it couldn't for some reason.

Comment: I think this makes the most sense as well. I have seen it used both ways, so I wasn't sure if there was some reason to use reject that I couldn't see.